# Creating relationship between 2 REST resources

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-boot, coding-style

I have 2 resources namely user and skill.
Both the resources can be created using a POST like the following:

1. POST /users {...}
2. POST /skills {...}

Users and skills can have a many-to-many relationship between them.

My idea is to PUT to /users/{userId}/skills/{skillId}

I am having a couple of questions here:

1. When I am making PUT request on /users/{userId}/skills/{skillId}, am I 
   creating a new resource or a sub-resource or just a relationship between exsiting resources?
2. What should be the status code to return after successful PUT on the above path?

Answer (score 1):

As I see, it's a relation one to many, so a user could have 0 to many skills, a skill will never have a user.

1 - If you are using a PUT, you won't be creating a new skill, so you just add a skill to an user.

2 - The status code should be 200 if the skill was successfully added to that user.